# How can I convert this object

Tags: javascript

```js
const obj = {
  acc: 34.4,
  code: 26.94,
  effect: 0,
  level: "D",
  avg_upper_20: "C",
}
```

how to convert above object to this type array

```js
[{subject: 'acc', score: 34.4}, {subject: 'code', score: 26.94}, {subject: 'effect', score: 0}]
```

not include level and avg_upper_20 property

please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Shouldn't be too difficult with a loop.

Answer (score 8):

```
const result = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(x => !['level', 'avg_upper_20'].includes(x))
  .map(x => ({subject: x, score: obj[x]}));
```

```js
const obj = {
  acc: 34.4,
  code: 26.94,
  effect: 0,
  level: "D",
  avg_upper_20: "C",
}

const result = Object.keys(obj).filter(x => !['level', 'avg_upper_20'].includes(x)).map(x => ({subject: x, score: obj[x]}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice clean one liner

Answer (score 4):

Try the following with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const obj = { acc: 34.4, code: 26.94, effect: 0, level: "D", avg_upper_20: "C", };

const entries = Object.entries(obj);
const result = entries.reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (k !== 'avg_upper_20' && k !== 'level') a.push({'subject': k, code: v});
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const obj = {
  acc: 34.4,
  code: 26.94,
  effect: 0,
  level: "D",
  avg_upper_20: "C",
};

const arr = [];
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key !== 'level' && key !== 'avg_upper_20') arr.push({ subject: key, score: value });
});

console.log(arr);
```

If statement excludes the two properties you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

try this it may works

const obj = {
      acc: 34.4,
      code: 26.94,
      effect: 0,
      level: "D",
      avg_upper_20: "C",
    };

```
const arr = [];
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key !== 'level' && key !== 'avg_upper_20') arr.push({ subject: key, score: value });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [{
  acc: 34.4,
  code: 26.94,
  effect: 0,
  level: "D",
  avg_upper_20: "C",
}];

let newArr = [];
arr.forEach( (item, idx) => {
  let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)); // copy object to unlink from original
  delete obj['avg_upper_20']; // delete avg_upper_20
  delete obj['level']; // delete level
  newArr.push(obj); // push to new array
});
```

assuming you have an array of objects not a single loose object